# Delay page redirect after form submit using jquery / js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is:

```
<input class="toBasketButton" type="submit" value="">
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry - what's a delay page redirect? Do you want to redirect somehow, or are you asking to intercept the form submit then do something, or something else?

Comment: @Rup I want to submit form then after some delay another page loads

Comment: You forgot to include an actual question. You just posted a line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$(function(){
    $('input.toBasketButton').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var button = this;
        window.setTimeout(function(form){
            $(form).submit();
        }, 1000, $(button).closest('form'));
    });
});

<form action="" method="post">
    <input class="toBasketButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

([Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/GJz4x/))

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery's ajaxForm plugin ( http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ )

This enables you to submit the form through ajax, which means you never leave the page until you want to. This way, you can have the user submit, perform whatever you need to do, once once you're done redirect via JS or through PHP as usual. The user won't know the difference - the delay will look the same to them, but you gain all the control inbetween the submit click, and the redirection, allowing you to perform whatever else you need.

Example:

```
$(form).ajaxForm({
    dataType:  "json", 
    success:   myFormSubmissionIsDone, 
    url: "/some/controller/action/", 
    type: "post", timeout: 30000
});

function myFormSubmissionIsDone() { 
      // This and that, whatever you need to do...
      window.location = "/newlocation/redirecting/now/yay";
 }
```