# I want to delay a form action, but still have it submit before I redirect

Tags: jquery

I have a standard form with some text inputs and a submit button at the bottom. Its action currently redirects to my homepage, but I want it to submit the form, and *then* redirect a second or two later.

I found a similar question at: [Delay page redirect after form submit using jquery / js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291512/delay-page-redirect-after-form-submit-using-jquery-js), but the answer there just delayed for a period of time, then submitted and redirected simultaneously.

If it's any help, here is a mini-version of my form

```
<form action="/home" onsubmit="createAdd({{ newID }}, {{ user.get_profile.id }})" class="form-horizontal" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="newName">Name*</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="newName" id="name" required>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"><i class="icon-wrench icon-white"> </i> Create </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My AJAX:

```
function createAdd(event, user){  

    $.ajax({
    url: '/eventsearch/eventsearch/createCustom/',
    type: "POST",
    data: {name: name, loc: loc, start: start, end: end, tags: tags, event_id: event, profile: user},
    success: function(){
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = '/eventsearch/eventsearch/';
        }, 2000);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have a jQuery code already?

Comment: I was trying to use what was in the link I posted above. Here, I'll post it.

Comment: Are you submitting the form via AJAX?  If it's a normal form POST (without AJAX) then the submit _is_ the redirect.  Either by going to the page to which it's posting or by being redirected by the server response from the post.  It's unclear what the actual order of events is that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm submitting with ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're submitting via AJAX then you'd want to set up the redirect (and its delay) in the success callback for the AJAX call.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // other AJAX options
    success: function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = someUrl;
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

This should wait 2 seconds after the AJAX success and then redirect the user to the new page.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying this, but my form resets all its fields as soon as I hit submit and the redirect never goes through.

Comment: @Xonal: How are you handling the submit?  My answer doesn't cover that, I was assuming you had that working already based on your comment on the question, "I'm submitting with ajax."  Can you update the question with your complete code?  Is the AJAX POST successful?  When you debug, at what point does it fail?

Comment: The submission is successful. The event is properly created. I'll update the code above to show you how I've appended your answer

Comment: @Xonal: I don't see any specific issue in the code you posted.  For the form reset, maybe change the submit button to a regular button so the form doesn't try to do a normal submit as well?  The same can usually be achieved by a `return false;` in the JavaScript handler, but just not using a `submit` type button in the first place also does the trick.

Comment: sorry I think I may not know enough to understand. When I change the button type to "button", then the form won't submit at all. Where would I place the `return false` code?

Comment: @Xonal: The button type is in the HTML markup.  Currently you have a `button type="submit"`.  Try just taking out the `type="submit"` entirely, or maybe changing it to `input type="button"`.  Both should do the same thing.  With that you shouldn't need the `return false;` but if you want to include it just in case it would be the last line in your `createAdd()` function.

Answer (score 1):

When you type a web address into the browser url bar you're submitting a "GET" request to that URL.

When you submit your form you are sending a "POST" request.

Both these requests send some (or no) data and receive a "response". In your current situation I presume that the response for both is just the standard HTML output if your page, which is then rendered in the browser (after you've done some processing).

So the GET flow goes like this:

1. Type address in URL bar
2. Press "go"
3. GET request is sent to your server
4. Your server responds with the HTML to render

And the POST something like this:

1. Fill out form
2. Press "submit" button
3. POST request is sent to your server
4. You pick up the POST variables and process them (maybe save to DB or similar)
5. Your server responds with the HTML to render

As you can see, the SUBMIT is part of the REDIRECT in these cases.

What you will need to do is to branch off the processing of the POST form and then redirect to the page you want to display.

To do this you will need to create another PHP script which will handle the POST request, do the processing and return with a success message. Then you need to redirect the user to the relevant page you wish to redirect to.

This would be the new flow:

1. Fill out form
2. Press "submit" button
3. Javascript creates an AJAX POST call to the processing URL:

   1. Processing script gets all POST variables and does what it needs to (save to DB or whatever)
   2. Processing script returns with HTTP/1.1 200 OK response.
4. On success javascript then starts a timer and redirects the user to the success page after a few seconds.

I hope this makes sense. If you need any more info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to submit the form via ajax (using something like jquery form plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), and then do your redirect from the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to wait for the ajax submit before redirecting, you can do the redirect in the success.

```
function createAdd(event, user){  

  $.ajax({
    url: '/eventsearch/eventsearch/createCustom/',
    type: "POST",
    data: {name: name, loc: loc, start: start, end: end, tags: tags, event_id: event, profile: user},
    success: function(){
      window.location = '/redirect/goes/here'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax you need to wait until the `done` callback is invoked since this means your `POST` request was successfull, and then you could redirect the user. Something like this:

```
function createAdd(event, user){  
  $.ajax({
  url: '/eventsearch/eventsearch/createCustom/',
  type: "POST",
  data: {name: name, loc: loc, start: start, end: end, tags: tags, event_id: event, profile: user}
  })
  .done(function(result) {
    // redirect as you like
    window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    // your request failed so do not redirect and handle the error
  });
}
```

Hope it helps.